# DLL на Delphi Embarcadero, IIS, многопоточность, работа с базой Firebird

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, firebird, iis, dll

Есть код:

```
{ Invokable implementation File for TBillingGaz which implements IBillingGaz }

unit BillingGazImpl;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, Types, XSBuiltIns, BillingGazIntf, WebService.ReturnRecord,
     Classes, SyncObjs, SysUtils, StrUtils, Messages;

type

  { TBillingGaz }
  TBillingGaz = class(TInvokableClass, IBillingGaz)
  public
    function echoDouble(const Value: Double): Double; stdcall;
    function GetBill(const AccountNo: string; const ConsumValue: Integer): TBillForClient; stdcall;
  end;

type
  TNThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FAcc : string;
    FCons : Integer;
    procedure Sync;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    property AccTh : string read FAcc write FAcc;// write Fcons;
    property Cons : Integer read Fcons write Fcons;
  end;

var
  acc: string;
  cons1, i: Integer;
  CS: TCriticalSection;
  mBillingGaz : TBillingGaz;

implementation

uses WebService.CalcPayAmount{, BillingGazThread};

function TBillingGaz.echoDouble(const Value: Double): Double; stdcall;
begin
  { TODO : Implement method echoDouble }
  Result := Value;
end;

function TBillingGaz.GetBill(const AccountNo: string; const ConsumValue: Integer): TBillForClient; stdcall;
var
  NewThread: TNThread;
  prevAcc : string;
begin
  Result := TBillForClient.Create;

  cons1 := 0;
  acc :=  AccountNo;
  prevAcc := AccountNo;
  Result.FullName := acc + ' ' + FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss.zzz', Now);

  NewThread:= TNThread.Create(true);
  NewThread.FreeOnTerminate:=true;
  NewThread.Priority:=tpLower;
  NewThread.AccTh := prevAcc;
  NewThread.Resume;
  Sleep(5);

  if Copy(Result.FullName, 1, 9) <> acc then
    Result.FullName := Result.FullName + ' ' + acc + ' ' + prevAcc;
  Result.ErrorCode := NewThread.Cons;
end;

procedure TNThread.Execute;
begin
  CS.Enter;
  case AnsiIndexText(Copy(AccTh, 1, 2), ['00','01','02','03','04','05']) of
    0 : begin
      Cons := 1;
    end;
    1 : begin
      Cons := 2;
    end;
    2 : begin
      Cons := 3;
    end;
    3 : begin
      Cons := 4;
    end;
    4 : begin
      Cons := 5;
    end;
    5 : begin
      Cons := 6;
    end
  else
    Cons := ERROR_WRONG_ACCOUNT_NO;
  CS.Leave;
end;

procedure TNThread.Sync;
begin
//  mBillingGaz.Billingcons := cons1;
end;

initialization
{ Invokable classes must be registered }
   InvRegistry.RegisterInvokableClass(TBillingGaz);
   CS := TCriticalSection.Create;

end.
```

Есть биллинговый проект. Он рабочий. Появилась необходимость создать веб-сервис для предоставления суммы к оплате за газ в ответ на запрос с передачей лицевого счета и текущего показания счетчика. Чтобы не изобретать велосипед, было решено взять готовый модуль проекта, отвечающий за расчеты и создать на его основе DLL для веб-сервера. Проведено тестирование сервиса: поочередно серверу передаются заранее заготовленные лицевые счета и показания, ответ выводится в МЕМО на клиенте. Это работает нормально, когда только один клиент обращается. Программа клиента была скопирована и запущена параллельно. Таким образом два клиента одновременно работают. У них 2 разных списка с лицевыми и показаниями. Обе программы работают какое-то время, потом появляется ошибка:

> List index out of bounds().

Порывшись в интернете обнаружил, что IIS работает в несколько потоков. А это чревато при работе с TList, который не потокобезопасен. При попытке перейти на TThreadList наткнулся на такую проблему: список на основе TList объявляется как:

```
var
  переменная: TList<какой-то класс>;
```

такая конструкция по-видимому TThreadList не поддерживается. Долго не заморочиваясь, решил создавать потоки прямо внутри удаленно вызываемой функции GetBill. Но тут наткнулся на проблему синхронизации. Бывает так, что запросы к серверу поступают одновременно и результат второго по очереди запроса попадает к первому.

Не удается организовать работу потоков. Что-то я делаю не так, возможно вообще в корне неверное, но не пойму как по-другому работать с потоками.

Comment: Не понял для чего нужен поток. Зачем для каждого запроса создавать новый поток?
Применение критической секции в Вашем коде бесполезно. Ее нужно ставить в методе `GetBill` и она должна быть не глобальной а принадлежать классу `TBillingGaz`, создаваться в конструкторе и уничтожаться в деструкторе. Критическая секция ресурс ОС и не стоит создавать новую каждый раз при загрузке библиотеки и не освобождать за собой.
Не нашел в Вашем коде `TList` о котором Вы говорили.
Запросы должны идти через критическую секцию, либо становиться в очередь. `Sleep` нужно убрать, заменить на TEvent и ожидать его.

Comment: переменная TList создается в другом модуле, который отвечает за подключение к базе по так называемому Алиасу.
function TdmDB.GetDatabaseByName(const ConnectionName: string): TpFIBDatabase;
var Conn: TssConnectionData;
  S: String;
begin
...какой-то код   
    if FDatabaseList <> nil then
      for Conn in FDatabaseList do
      begin
        if AnsiSameText(Conn.Name, ConnectionName)  then
          Exit(Conn.Database);
      end;
...какой-то код
if FDatabaseList = nil then
        FDatabaseList := TObjectList<TssConnectionData>.Create(True);
      FDatabaseList.Add(Conn);
...какой-то код
end

Comment: а как работать с TEvent? По крайней мере, где примеры посмотреть?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent